# Refreshed cn1lib files, but still the same error: "ClassNotFoundException WebSocketNativeImplImpl"

Tags: websocket, codenameone

I want to use `websockets` in my `Codename One` project.
So far I copied the `cn1-websockets.cn1` lib into my project's lib, refreshed the `cn1lib` files, and I'm still getting:

> ClassNotFoundException WebSocketNativeImplImpl

What I am getting:

```
D:\PIDEV\fixit-mobile\fixit-mobile\lib\impl\native\javase\com\codename1\io\websocket\WebSocketNativeImplImpl.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
public class WebSocketNativeImplImpl implements com.codename1.io.websocket.WebSocketNativeImpl {
symbol: class WebSocketNativeImpl
location: package com.codename1.io.websocket

D:\PIDEV\fixit-mobile\fixit-mobile\lib\impl\native\javase\com\codename1\io\websocket\WebSocketNativeImplImpl.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
WebSocket.openReceived(id);
symbol: variable WebSocket
```

Same for:

```
WebSocket.errorReceived(id, t.getMessage(), 0, t);
WebSocket.messageReceived(id, text);
WebSocket.errorReceived(id, t.getMessage(), 0, t);
WebSocket.messageReceived(id, binary);
WebSocket.errorReceived(id, t.getMessage(), 0, t);
```

So obviously it can't find the `websocket` class or something like this.
I copied the `websocket` class I found in the `cn1-websockets-demo` project to my project, but it still doesn't work.
Any help? I would be thankful :)

Comment: Which IDE are you using and how did you install the cn1lib? Try sending a build, it should trigger a rebuild of the project which might resolve the issue. Make sure to remove the class you copied as it might disrupt this process.

Comment: Hey, I got it to work by explicitly copying the `Websocket` class into a the package `codename1.io.websocket`, I still don't get why it doesn't come with the `cn1-websockets.cn1`, but yeah, am using Netbeans, and I installed it using the extensions tool, but now it works, thanks.

Comment: Which version of the plugin do you have. What's the printout in the console after you do a refresh libs?

Comment: The latest version, the printout is what the message I included in the question

Comment: That's not the full printout after refresh libs